# Only execute a task if the executable exists

Tags: gradle

I try to execute a task only if the executable exists. From what I have found so far one should use the `onlyIf` but if the binary is not existing the evaluation of the onlyif fails (and so does the task). So how should one really do this. I think this is quite a common use case so there must be some standard solution to this kind of problem or not?

```
task test(type: Exec) {

    onlyIf {
        def result = exec { 
            ignoreExitValue = true
            commandLine 'wskz', '--help'
        }

        result.exitValue != 0
    }

    commandLine 'wskz', '--help'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that an executable exists by executing it, you could put a try-catch inside the `onlyIf` predicate like this.

```gradle
task test(type: Exec) {

    onlyIf {
        try {
            def result = exec { 
                ignoreExitValue = true
                commandLine 'wskz', '--help'
            }
            result.exitValue != 0
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }

    commandLine 'wskz', '--help'
}
```

Trying to execute the program to see whether it 'exists' might not be the best option though.

- What if the program exists but isn't on your `PATH`?
- What if the current user doesn't have permission to execute the program?
- It might take just as long to execute the program to see if it exists as it would to attempt the full task execution.

I don't know what you would want the behaviour of your build to be in these situation, so I can't propose a definitive alternative. One suggestion would be to simply use `File.canExecute()` inside your `onlyIf`, possibly combined with a call to [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which)/[`where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) if you need to search the `PATH`.

Comment: true, but `wich` / `where` are not available on windows. I want to make a task to deploy to openwhisk using the wsk cli. if it's not existing you can not deploy this part of the project but all other submodules. printing a warning in such a case should be good enough.

Comment: `where` is a windows command. See the page I linked it to in my answer.

Comment: interesting `where` in powershell does nothing but indeed this is a dos command. thx for the heads up!